# Grafana do not shows custom logs

Tags: python, grafana, grafana-loki

my problem with grafana is that it does not show logs uploaded with `python` (requests library) or with `Postman`, when I use `curl` command everything works as expected. But with /series endpoint logs uploaded with python are discoverable:

[image: Series query]

Also with `http://localhost:3100/loki/api/v1/label/job/values` logs are present:

```json
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        "paweljob22",
        "simpleJsonJob",
        "varlogs"
    ]
}
```

Python source code looks like in this medium example https://medium.com/geekculture/pushing-logs-to-loki-without-using-promtail-fc31dfdde3c6

But in grafana results can be discover only for `curl` uploaded logs.

[image]

Comment: Use query inspector and inspect request/response.

Comment: Query is the same, but results is empty.
![Query compare](https://previews.dropbox.com/p/thumb/ABke34QxdCDMWPuRQ1NubcPtT8u760cbaSJ8_7VoDo7RXVIlhOTCKpDEAJkv2oCHe1FiltvBzb8OnYyBBUbt9HD9qcVcRRZmhzXsXD7dEjmN-gSrgpNY_XBE2bmSZ91Ypl66t8ld5yJ8k_Ft_tEckzNQQuS0_8XKQWeSqq3ijvy7tQczboyvMTacEOove1ecYNSmdhLTt1R5Zo5OFqz-vlgu1QM5bi_8Zn0k2B67JOPrMc__nBKmxy25cEUfYsrk8lKlQ3jfpvag2lEfseVc_uHsoeU8uTkVztUpZyVIdsCTirIcUQp_dM80cHrlC_lzJCNpM8B_g9RWxFnyKWoQl9Vv_b2K6N4feGFB62OUPqs7fli-zQpwpUvPW3bzqj2AhWs/p.jpeg)